# How to expose accounts in truffle?

Tags: truffle, addresses

I am working with the basic `truffle` framework. The `MetaCoin.sol` file which is installed automatically has the following

```
contract MetaCoin {
    mapping (address => uint) balances;

    function MetaCoin() {
        balances[tx.origin] = 10000;        
    }...
```

What this accomplishes is adding 10000 MetaCoin into account 0. What I want to do is access account 1, 2, 3, perhaps to add MetaCoin or do something else. But I don't know how to do this. I can do it by explicitly including the address (e.g. `balances[0x90afa53bce...]`) but this is bad because truffle addresses are not static between sessions.

I know that truffle tests starts out with all accounts in a list, but I want to access them within the contract first, and then test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the truffle console you can access them with web3.eth.getBalance(web3.eth.accounts[0]), just replace the zero.

In a Javascript file you can easily access them as showed in the basic metacoin test:

```
var MetaCoin = artifacts.require("./MetaCoin.sol");

contract('MetaCoin', function(accounts) {
  it("should put 10000 MetaCoin in the first account", function() {
    return MetaCoin.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      return instance.getBalance.call(accounts[0]);
    }).then(function(balance) {
      assert.equal(balance.valueOf(), 10000, "10000 wasn't in the first account");
    });
  });
});
```

In principle the contract doesn't know on which network it's deployed, therefore I'm not sure that you can do it from within the solidity contract.